# Advice on removing records completely from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am looking for some advice on the best way to remove multiple records (approximatley over 3000) completly from a database. I have been assigned a job of removing old records from our database for GDPR reasons.

However this is a database i do not have much knowledge on and there is no documentation, ERD's etc on how the tables are joined together.

I managed to work out the tables which will need to have records removed to completely remove details from the database, there are about 24 tables which need to have records removed from.

I have a list of ID numbers which need to be removed so i was thinking of creating a temporary table with the list of IDs and then creating a stored procedure to loop through the temproary tables. Then for each of the 24 tables check to see if it contains records connected to the ID number and then if they do delete them.

Does anyone know if there is any better way of removing these records??

Comment: basically, you want to do "delete from table_name where some_id = [some_parameter]". Why are you using a temp table here instead of directly deleting from the DB?

Comment: Since you don't know your database, maybe model it first, create a backup so you can be sure you don't make unrecoverable mistakes it. And next to that what @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram said

Comment: Because i have about 3000 different ID records to remove so i was going to use a temp table so i could loop through the 3000 odd numbers and use variables to delete the records. I have been trying to create ERDs for the database to try and figure out how it is all joined together but there is no way i can be 100% sure they are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table variable and union all:

```
declare @ids table (id int primary key)

insert into @ids (id) 
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
...
select 3000

delete from table_name where id in
(select id from @ids)
```

Obviously just change the numbers to the actual ids

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i will try that way as it seems a little less complicated

Comment: @GordonLinoff - right you are, I have edited the post and corrected it, thanks